# Azure Media Service Videos are not working on Android and iOS Real Devices React Native

Tags: azure, react-native, webview, azure-media-services, video-player

I have embed Azure Media Player in WebView. Its working fine on android emulator and iOS simulator. Its also working fine on android real device in debug but its not working on android devices in release version. For iOS its not working on real devices in debug and release version.

Here is code sample...

````
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.3.6/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.3.6/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"></video>
    <script>
        var myOptions = {
          "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
          controls: true,
          autoplay: true,
          width:1000,
          height: "1000",
        }
        myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
        myPlayer.src([
            {
                "src": "https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest",
                "type": "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
            }
        ]);
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>;

  return (
          <WebView
            source={{ html: htmlContent }}
          />
    )
        ```

Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!
````

Answer (score 1):

If you are building native applications on Android, i would highly recommend that you use ExoPlayer and not AMP.

For iOS, you should also always default to use the native built in AvPlayer framework. AMP does not add much (or any) value on the iOS side, as it just hands off control to the native iOS media framework (AVPlayer) where all the processing and parsing of HLS is going to happen anyways.

Have you already tested your streams playing back in iOS in the native player? Did you pass the HLS manifest to the player and not the Smooth Streaming manifest?

Comment: We are not building native application on android or iOS. We are using react native to build android and iOS app. The code I have shared above is working fine in case of android in debug and release but still its not working on iOS real devices.

Comment: We have website associated with mobile app, so our final solution is host the above code on web and just passing that URL in WebView in mobile app and its working fine in both android and iOS.

Comment: Good to hear Nauman, glad you have a working solution now.